# Free(), Access Violation и Динамическая память

Tags: c, winapi, динамические-структуры, free

Дoбрый вeчeр.

Код:

```
// STD  библиотеки и заголовки
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// Windows библиотеки и заголовки
#include <windows.h>

// Пределы переменных
#include <limits.h>

// Подключение настроек
#include <Settings.h>

/* ПОТОКИ */

DWORD WINAPI SafeСycleThreadF(LPVOID);  // Поток безопасного прохода


/* Структуры */

// Структура простой задачи
struct simple_task {
    unsigned int root;
    unsigned int* tail;
};

// Структура буфера задач
struct taskbuffer {
    unsigned long long int CurrNum;
    unsigned long long int* TaskCount;
    struct simple_task** Tasks;

} TaskBuffer;

// Структура графа
struct graph_my {
    unsigned long long int count;
    unsigned int* freelist;
    unsigned int** grmatrix;
} GHT;

// Очередь процессов
struct prlist {
    unsigned int root;
    unsigned int* tail;
    bool check;
    unsigned char status;
};

// Оберка для очередей процессов
struct PL {
    unsigned long long int count;
    struct prlist* gl;
    bool busy;
    bool found;
} PL_L;

/* Сигнатура функций */
unsigned char GetAvThreads(unsigned char); // Получение числа доступных потоков
void PrintWelcome(); // Печать экрана приветствия
void PrintSys(unsigned char); // Печать информации и системе
bool Graph_Create(FILE**); // Печать графа
void FileInput(); // Ввод, анализ и т.п. файла
void Taskmgr_Initialize(); // Иницианализация диспетчера потоков
void Taskmgr_Start(unsigned char); // Запуск диспетчера потоков


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// //
// ОСНОВНОЙ ПОТОК
// //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
int main() {

    /* ПЕРЕМЕННЫЕ */

    unsigned int* Ccmass; // Массив, содержащий в себе цикл

    unsigned char avthreads; //Доступно потоков

    bool found;

    FILE* file = NULL; // Файл

    ////////////////////
    /* ОСНОВНОЙ ПОТОК */
    ////////////////////

    // Изменение оформления консоли
    if (Styled_console == true)
        system("color F1");

    // Вывод экрана приветствия
    if (Welcome_logo_show == true) PrintWelcome();

    // Вычисляем кол-во ядер
    avthreads = GetAvThreads(ThreadLimit);

    // Вывод системных даных на экран
    if (SysInfo_show == true) PrintSys(ThreadLimit);

    // Ввод адресса
    FileInput();

    // Постановка задач в список
    Taskmgr_Initialize();

    // Небольшое исправление для потоков
    if (avthreads > 1) avthreads--; //Т.к. главный поток - тоже поток

    // Выполнение задач
    Taskmgr_Start(avthreads);


    //
    // Вывод
    /*
    found = false;
    for (positionnn = 0; positionnn < PL_count; positionnn++) {

          // Лог отладка

          printf("--------------------\n");
          printf("%u", PL[positionnn].root);printf("\n");
          printf("%u", PL[positionnn].tail[0]);printf("\n");
          for (first = 1; first <= PL[positionnn].tail[0]; first++) {
            printf("%u", PL[positionnn].tail[first]);printf("\t");
          }printf("\n");
          printf("%u", PL[positionnn].check);printf("\n");


        if (PL[positionnn].check == 8) {
            found = true;
            printf("Found cycle: ");

            kek = 1;
            while (PL[positionnn].tail[kek] != PL[positionnn].root) kek++;
            kek--;

            Ccmass = (unsigned int*)malloc((PL[positionnn].tail[0]-kek+2)*sizeof(unsigned int));
            Ccmass[0] = PL[positionnn].tail[0] - kek + 1;

            first = 1;
            for (lol = kek+1; lol <= PL[positionnn].tail[0]; lol++) {
              Ccmass[first] = PL[positionnn].tail[lol];
              first++;
            }
            Ccmass[Ccmass[0]] =  PL[positionnn].root;

            for (first = 1; first <= Ccmass[0]; first++) {
                printf("%u", Ccmass[first]);
                if (first != Ccmass[0]) printf("->");
            }
            printf("\n");

            free(Ccmass);
        }

    }

    if (found == false)
        printf("Cycles not found!\n");

    */

    if (PauseOnExit == true) system("pause");
    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// //
// Потоки безопасного выполнения
// //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Проход по графам и поиск циклов
DWORD WINAPI SafeСycleThreadF(LPVOID t) {

    unsigned long long int position = 0; // Текущая позиция
    unsigned long long int i, j; // Тикер (Для тех нужд)
    unsigned char CurPos; // позиция во временном буфере

    // Присоединение к временному буферу
    CurPos =  TaskBuffer.CurrNum;

    // Инициализация потока
    while (PL_L.gl[position].check != false) position++;
    PL_L.gl[position].check = true;
    PL_L.busy = false; // Показываем, что определили свой порядковый номер

    // Обнуленеие задач в временном буфере
    TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos] = 0;

    // Ищем цикл
    if (PL_L.gl[position].tail[0] != 0) {
      for (i = 1; i <= PL_L.gl[position].tail[0]; i++) {
        if (PL_L.gl[position].root == PL_L.gl[position].tail[i])
          PL_L.gl[position].status = true;
          PL_L.found = true;
      }
    }

    // Если не найден ни один цикл, то
    if (PL_L.gl[position].status != true) {
        for (i = 0; i < GHT.count; i++) {
            if (GHT.grmatrix[0][i] == PL_L.gl[position].root) {
                TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]++;

                TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos] = (struct simple_task*)realloc(TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos], TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]*(sizeof(struct simple_task)));
                TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos][TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]-1].root = GHT.grmatrix[1][i];
                TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos][TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]-1].tail = (unsigned int*)malloc((PL_L.gl[position].tail[0]+2)*sizeof(unsigned int));
                TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos][TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]-1].tail[0] = PL_L.gl[position].tail[0]+1;
                for (j = 1; j <= PL_L.gl[position].tail[0]; j++) {
                  TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos][TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]-1].tail[j] = PL_L.gl[position].tail[j];
                }
                TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos][TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]-1].tail[TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos][TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]-1].tail[0]] = PL_L.gl[position].root;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// //
// Дополнительные Функции
// //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Вычисление ядер процессора
unsigned char GetAvThreads(unsigned char limit){

    // Пременные
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo; // Инфо о системе
    unsigned char Result;

    // Основной код

        // Вычисляем количество ядер процессора
        GetSystemInfo(&sysinfo);
        Result = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;

        // Применяем ограничитель
        if ((limit != 0) && (limit < Result)) {
            Result = limit;
        }

        // Фикс для странных Win ОС
        if (((Result > 250) || (Result < 1)) && (CPUFix == true)) Result = 1;

        return Result;
}

// Функция печати приветствия
void PrintWelcome() {
    printf("Programm by Igor Burenkov\n");
    printf("Variant: 6\n");
    printf("You're welcome!\n\n");
}

// Функция печати данных о системе
void PrintSys(unsigned char avthreads) {

    // Переменные
    unsigned char cpucores;
    SYSTEM_INFO sysinfo; // Инфо о системе

    // Основной код

    cpucores = sysinfo.dwNumberOfProcessors;

    printf("---- System Info ----\n");
    printf("\nAvailable Cores: ");
    printf("%u", cpucores);
    printf("\nAvailable Threads: ");
    if ((avthreads != 0) && (avthreads < cpucores)) {
      cpucores = avthreads;
    }

    printf("%u", cpucores);
    printf("\n");
    printf("\n---------------------\n");
}

// Ввод файла
void FileInput(){
    // Переменные
    FILE *file = NULL;
    char fadr[2048];

    // Получение файла и создание графа
    while ((file == NULL)||(Graph_Create(&file)==false)) {
        if (file != NULL) printf("Broken file.\n");
        printf("Please specify graph file adress:\n");
        scanf("%s", fadr);
        file = fopen(fadr, "r");
        if (file == NULL) printf("Wrong adress or file.\n");
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// //
// Работа с графами
// //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Функция создания графа
bool Graph_Create(FILE **file){

     // Переменные
     unsigned long long int i, j, k, m;  //Обычные тикеры для циклов
     unsigned int first, sec;

     // Если файл пуст
     if (*file == NULL) return false;


     // Считывание вершин
     fscanf((*file), "%u", &first);
     GHT.freelist = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
     GHT.freelist[0] = 0;
     while (first != 0) {
         GHT.freelist[0]++;
         GHT.freelist = (unsigned int*)realloc(GHT.freelist, (GHT.freelist[0]+1)*sizeof(unsigned int));
         GHT.freelist[GHT.freelist[0]] = first;
         fscanf((*file), "%u", &first);
     }

    // Cчитывание связей
    GHT.count = 0;
    GHT.grmatrix = (unsigned int**)malloc(2 * sizeof(unsigned int*));
    GHT.grmatrix[0] = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    GHT.grmatrix[1] = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
    while (fscanf((*file), "%u%u", &first, &sec) == 2) {
        if (sec != first) GHT.count++;
        GHT.count++;
        GHT.grmatrix[0] = (unsigned int*)realloc(GHT.grmatrix[0], GHT.count*sizeof(unsigned int));
        GHT.grmatrix[1] = (unsigned int*)realloc(GHT.grmatrix[1], GHT.count*sizeof(unsigned int));

        GHT.grmatrix[0][GHT.count - 1] = first;
        GHT.grmatrix[1][GHT.count - 1] = sec;

        if (sec != first) {
          GHT.grmatrix[0][GHT.count - 2] = sec;       GHT.grmatrix[1][GHT.count - 2] = first;
        }
    }
    fclose(*file);

    // Удаление дублей
    m = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < GHT.count; i++) {
        for (j = i+1; j < GHT.count; j++) {
            if ((GHT.grmatrix[0][i] == GHT.grmatrix[0][j]) && (GHT.grmatrix[1][i] == GHT.grmatrix[1][j])) {
                for (k=j+1; k < GHT.count; k++) {
                   GHT.grmatrix[0][k-1] = GHT.grmatrix[0][k];
                   GHT.grmatrix[1][k-1] = GHT.grmatrix[1][k];
                }
                m++;
            }
        }
    }
    GHT.count = GHT.count - m;
    GHT.grmatrix[0] = (unsigned int*)realloc(GHT.grmatrix[0], GHT.count*sizeof(unsigned int));
    GHT.grmatrix[1] = (unsigned int*)realloc(GHT.grmatrix[1], GHT.count*sizeof(unsigned int));

    return true;
}



/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// //
// Работа с потоками
// //
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// Инициализация диспетчера потоков-задач
void Taskmgr_Initialize(){

    // Переменные
    unsigned long long int kek;

    // Постановка задач в список
    PL_L.count = GHT.freelist[0];
    PL_L.gl = (struct prlist*)realloc(PL_L.gl, (PL_L.count)*(sizeof(struct prlist)));
    for (kek = 1; kek <= GHT.freelist[0]; kek++) {
        PL_L.gl[kek - 1].root = GHT.freelist[kek];
        PL_L.gl[kek - 1].tail = (unsigned int*)malloc(sizeof(unsigned int));
        PL_L.gl[kek - 1].tail[0] = 0;
        PL_L.gl[kek - 1].check = false;
        PL_L.gl[kek - 1].status = false;
    }

    // Доп. иницианализации
    PL_L.found = false;
    PL_L.busy =  false;

}

// Запуск диспетчера потоков
void Taskmgr_Start(unsigned char limit){

   // Потоки
   HANDLE* SafeСycleCheck; // Поток вывода экрана приветствия

   // Переменные
   unsigned long long int position = 0; // Текужая позиция с списке задач
   unsigned char curlimit; // Кол-во потоков, используемых в данном конкретном цикле
   unsigned char i, j, k; // Тикер (Для циклов)

   // Цикл выполнения задач
    while (position < PL_L.count) {

        // Выставляем кол-во потоков
        if ((PL_L.count - position) < limit)
            curlimit = PL_L.count - position;
        else  curlimit = limit;

        // Создаем массив потоков
        SafeСycleCheck = (HANDLE*)malloc(curlimit*sizeof(HANDLE));

        // Создаем списоки буфера задач
        TaskBuffer.Tasks = (struct simple_task**)malloc(curlimit*sizeof(struct simple_task*));
        TaskBuffer.TaskCount = (unsigned long long int*)malloc(curlimit*sizeof(unsigned long long int));

        // Запускаем потоки
        for (i = 0; i < curlimit; i++) {
            // Ожидание инициализации предыдущего потока
            while (PL_L.busy != false);
            PL_L.busy = true;
            // Запуск потока
            TaskBuffer.CurrNum = i;
            SafeСycleCheck[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, SafeСycleThreadF, NULL, 0, NULL);
        }

        // Ожидание выполнения всех потоков
        for (i = 0; i < curlimit; i++) WaitForSingleObject(SafeСycleCheck[i], INFINITE);


        // Склейка и освобождение памяти временного буфера
        for (i = 0; i < curlimit; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < TaskBuffer.TaskCount[i]; j++) {
                PL_L.count++;
                PL_L.gl = (struct prlist*)realloc(PL_L.gl, PL_L.count*(sizeof(struct prlist)));
                PL_L.gl[PL_L.count-1].check = false;
                PL_L.gl[PL_L.count-1].status = false;
                PL_L.gl[PL_L.count-1].root = TaskBuffer.Tasks[i][j].root;
                PL_L.gl[PL_L.count-1].tail = (unsigned int*)malloc((TaskBuffer.Tasks[i][j].tail[0]+1) * sizeof(unsigned int));
                for (k = 0; k <= TaskBuffer.Tasks[i][j].tail[0]; k++) {
                    PL_L.gl[PL_L.count-1].tail[k] = TaskBuffer.Tasks[i][j].tail[k];
                }
                free(TaskBuffer.Tasks[i][j].tail);
            }
            free(TaskBuffer.Tasks[i]);
        }

        free(TaskBuffer.Tasks);

        // Освобождение памяти
        free(TaskBuffer.TaskCount);
        free(SafeСycleCheck);

        // Повышение позиции в списке
        position = position + curlimit;
    }
}
```

При попытке реализовать освобождение памяти - вылетает ошибка.

Точное место ошибки в коде:

```
free(TaskBuffer.Tasks);
```

Не понимаю причины ошибки - можете помочь?

Файл для тестов
m.txt

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
0
1 1
1 2
3 3
2 1
6 2
6 3
4 4
3 2
```

Cпaсибo!

P.S. Забыл файл с настройками
Settings.h

```
#ifndef SETTINGS_H
 #define SETTINGS_H

    ///////////////
    /* НАСТРОЙКИ */
    ///////////////

    // Технические
    const unsigned char ThreadLimit = 1; // Ограничение кол-ва потоков (Если 0, то ThreadLimit = CPU_cores, Если 1, то без учета главного потока, Если больше 1, то с учетом главного)
    const bool CPUFix = true; // Фикс числа CPU для запуска на странных ОС [Отключить, если у вас больше 250 ядер]

    // Визуальные
    const bool Welcome_logo_show = true; // Выводить приветствие
    const bool Styled_console = true; // Изменить оформление консоли
    const bool SysInfo_show = true; // Выводить на экран количество ядер

    // Отладка
    const bool PauseOnExit = true; // Выводить Сообщение-Паузу перед выходом

 #endif
```

Comment: Отойду в душ - буду через 15 мин

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваша программа падает уже на самом первом вызове

```
TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos] = (struct simple_task*)realloc(TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos], TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]*(sizeof(struct simple_task)));
```

потому что в этом месте `TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos]` содержит неинициализированное значение. Память под массив `TaskBuffer.Tasks` вы выделяли через `malloc` и никаких попыток инициализировать элементы этого массива вы не предпринимали.

Comment: Так TaskBuffer.Tasks - это динамический двумерный массив стуктур. Я сперва смалочил его по первой коодинате (TaskBuffer.Tasks = (struct simple_task**)malloc(curlimit*sizeof(struct simple_task*));)

Comment: После - выделил память для 2й координаты, уже через реаллок (TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos] = (struct simple_task*)realloc(TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos], TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos]*(sizeof(struct simple_task)));)

Comment: И только после инициировал root и tail

Comment: По правилу из ООП - деаллочил в обратном порядке

Comment: @SlimRG: Это прекрасно. Но еще раз повторяю: `TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos]` **содержит неинициализированное значение**. А вы это мусорное значение пихаете в `realloc`. Дальше смотреть нет смысла.

Comment: Т.е. tail -> 2я координата -> 1я координата -> база

Comment: а какое неинициированное значение он содержит и как его проинициировать?

Comment: сорри, если выгляжу глупо - я учусь только

Comment: @SlimRG: "а какое неинициированное значение он содержит"? Это шутка? Там сидит непредсказуемый мусор.

Comment: не так выразился - в каком месте и у какого элемента получается неинициированные данные. И как бы вы их проинициировали?

Comment: У вас хватило соображалки сделать `TaskBuffer.TaskCount[CurPos] = 0;`? Почему же вы там же не сообразили сделать `TaskBuffer.Tasks[CurPos] = NULL;`???

Comment: ааааа, дошло - спасибо

Comment: огромное спасибо - все заработало - еще не со всем разобрался в Си, все же еще учусь - так что извините, что задаю порой глупые вопросы